# Javascript ResizeObserver is triggered unexpected

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Why the `ResizeObserver` class always execute the handler at the first `observe()`?

Try execute the code below on Chrome' dev tool:

```js
(new ResizeObserver(() => console.log('resize detected'))).observe($0)
```

You will see the log printed immediately after you apply it, even if you didn't do any size change.

I need the resize observer that only executes the handler on resize.
Is there any hack/options to tweak it?

```js
let disableObserver = false;

const obs = new ResizeObserver(() => {
   if (!disableObserver) {
      console.log('resize detected');
   }
});

// the hack below doesn't work:
disableObserver = true;
obs.observe(someElement);
disableObserver = false;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested in different browsers and the reported behaviour is consistent - observer callback is called when `observer()` is called.

I've checked the [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer/#intro), it says:

> - Observation will fire when watched Element is inserted/removed from DOM.
> - Observation will fire when watched Element display gets set to none.
> - Observations do not fire for non-replaced inline Elements.
> - Observations will not be triggered by CSS transforms.
> - Observation will fire when observation starts if Element is being rendered, and Element’s size is not 0,0.

I guess initial call is because of Element being rendered.

Each element can be added to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to skip initial call. Something like this:

```
let entriesSeen = new Set(); // set of entries to skip initial resize call

const obs = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
        if (!entriesSeen.has(entry.target)) {
            // do nothing during initial call
            // just mark element as seen
            entriesSeen.add(entry.target);
        } else {
            console.log('resize detected');
            console.log(entry.target);
        }
    }
});

obs.observe(someElement);
```

Comment: i've no idea why by design is like that. Logically the **Resize** Observer is doing anything related to the element's size, nothing else.

Comment: *Observation will fire when watched Element is inserted/removed from DOM* => it's the MutationObserver job, why the ResizeObserver doing the same stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote Wrapper for build-in ResizeObserver which reacts only on sizeChanging and ignores hiding and displaying.

```
    class ResizeObserverWrapper {

    _lastWidth;
    _lastHeight;

    observe(htmlElement, onSizeChanged) {

        new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            if (entries != undefined && entries.length > 0) {
                const newWidth = entries[0].target.clientWidth;
                const newHeight = entries[0].target.clientHeight;


                if (newWidth != undefined && newWidth > 0
                    && newHeight != undefined && newHeight > 0
                ) {
                    let dimensionChanged = newWidth != this._lastWidth && this._lastWidth > 0
                        || newHeight != this._lastHeight  && this._lastHeight > 0 ;
                    this._lastHeight = newHeight;
                    this._lastWidth = newWidth;
                    if (dimensionChanged) {
                        onSizeChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).observe(htmlElement);
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
new ResizeObserverWrapper().observe(yourRootElement.querySelector('.some-css-class'), () => console.log("It is resized"));
```